# disable automatic rescaling of y-axes data in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I plot data with matplotlib which have a very small y scale, matplotlib automatically changes the plot, so to plot appropriately rescaled data.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook

data = np.array([ [ 10, 0.500001 ], [20, 0.500002 ], [30, 0.500003 ] ])
plt.errorbar(x = data[:, 0], y = data[:, 1], fmt='o', capsize=2)
```

This code produces this result:

[image: matplotlib plot]

I would like to have the data plotted *as they are*, without shift and rescaling, so that in the y axes you see numbers like "0.500001", etc.

How can I disable this feature?